# Optimum query delay for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, yui

In a [yui AutoComplete](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete) or similar how many milliseconds are you using as [query delay](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/#delay) (time between the last key input and the request to the server)?

I recently changed the default value of an autocomplete cotrol similar to yui's from 750ms to 280ms using [Keystroke-Level Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KLM_(human_computer_interaction)) as a reference.

Any other useful references out there?

Comment: I set it to 0 so that autocomplete returns instantly.

Comment: @Alfred but what if the person enters only 1 character? You'll get a LOT of results that are displayed...

Comment: @omouse I was talking about query delay. I wanted the result to be displayed immediately. I was not talking about number of characters typed before returning results.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your purpose, I think. In my scenario I wanted them to not be intrued on if they knew exactly what they wanted. If they hesitate at all, help is there. For that, I used .3 or .5.

If you want to make their life easier by suggesting completions you can set it to 0 like Google does.